# JQ: exclude specified embedded keys

Tags: jq

From the following input:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key_x": "1",
        ...
        "key_z": "2"
    },
    "key2": {
        "key_x": "2",
        ...
        "key_z": "3"
    }
}
```

I would like to exclude all keys with the name `"key_x"` so the result should be

```
{
    "key1": {
        ...
        "key_z": "2"
    },
    "key2": {
        ...
        "key_z": "3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`del()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del%28path_expression%29) function:

```
jq 'del(.[]|.key_x)' input.json
```